# Template specialization for int = 0

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I want to implement my own std::tuple, without looking into an official implementation, but I'm getting a C2768 error (visual studio).

I've read compilator doesn't know if this is a template specialization or a completely new definition of a function, but I don't know how it would assume this is a new function

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct _tuple_node {
    T value;
    _tuple_node<Ts...> next;

    constexpr _tuple_node(T value, Ts... rest) : value(value), next(rest...) {
    }
};

template<class T>
struct _tuple_node<T> {
    T value;
    
    constexpr _tuple_node(T value) : value(value) {
    }
};

template<class... Ts> 
struct tuple {
    _tuple_node<Ts...> first;

    constexpr tuple(Ts... args) : first(args...) {
    }
};

template<int i, class T, class... Ts>
auto _get_t(_tuple_node<T, Ts...>& t) {
    return _get_t<i - 1, Ts...>(t.next);
}

template<class T, class... Ts>
auto _get_t<0, T, Ts...>(_tuple_node<T, Ts...>& t) {  //here
    return t.value;
}

template<int i, class T>
auto _get_t(_tuple_node<T>& t) {
    return t.value;
}

template<int i, class... Ts>
auto get(tuple<Ts...>& t) {
    return _get_t<i>(t.first);
}


int main() {
    tuple foo(1, std::string("test"));

    std::cout << get<0>(foo);
}
```

Comment: clangs gives better explanation: https://godbolt.org/z/dn68jovea

Comment: If you're using C++17 then something like `if constexpr (i == 0) { return t.value } else { return _get_t<i - 1, Ts...>(t.next); }` could work instead of partial specialization.

Comment: @MilesBudnek but when ```t.value``` and ```_get_t<i - 1, Ts...>(t.next);``` have different types then compiler cannot deduce return type. This doesn't have any sense for me because ```i``` is constexpr, but I've already tested that before

Comment: @fpekal `if constexpr` discards branches that it doesn't take (as long as it's applied to a template parameter).  That means the different branches can return different types, and the `auto` return type placeholder will deduce the correct one for the given `i`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/4xoYP3vKM)

Comment: @MilesBudnek Wow, I didn't note that "constexpr" there! Thank you so much